# Find the difference between 2 values inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to find the numeric difference between 2 values inside an object.

My objects are done like this:

```
{ today: 9, lastMonth: 6 }
```

I'm inside an every() method:

```
const validation = Object.values(myObj).every(item => console.log(item))
```

The every method is inside a reduce() method, because i have an array of object like the one i write up here.

Right now item log is printing value without any connection to the previous object,
but one by one, so seems that i can't do a difference between the value like so:

```
function difference(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}
```

What i expect:

```
(item => difference(item))
```

to find the difference between the 2 values present in my object

What is happening:

Difference is returning NaN because item are not taken together

**Edit**: I fixed the main problem, now i have a simple array like so:

```
[[0,2],[4,9],[5,7]]...
```

seems that Math.abs(a-b) doesn't work with array, there is a valid solution to this?

Comment: try (item => difference(item) || 0)

Comment: @Amit returns 0 everytime. can you check the edited question?

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as you call the difference function the result should be as expected.

I'd suggest creating a wrapper `getDifferences()` function to implement this:

```js
function difference(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}
   
function getDifferences(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => difference(...Object.values(el)));
}

console.log(getDifferences([{ today: 9, lastMonth: 6 }]));
console.log(getDifferences([[0,2],[4,9],[5,7]]));
console.log(getDifferences([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 3 }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also use [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), this will also allow you to pass an array of arguments to a function:

```js
function difference(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}
   
function getDifferences(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => difference.apply(null, Object.values(el)));
}

console.log(getDifferences([{ today: 9, lastMonth: 6 }]));
console.log(getDifferences([[0,2],[4,9],[5,7]]));
console.log(getDifferences([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 3 }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function difference(array) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   result.push(Math.abs(array[i][0]-array[i][1]));
}
return result
}
var arr = [[0,2],[4,9],[5,7]]
console.log(difference(arr))
```